# Using Tagit with PHP and MySQL: Generating Tags From Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

So I'm new to jQuery and I am trying to use Tagit to create dynamic tags.  What the script offers is the ability to show a list of possible tags for the user to click on and have as one of their tags.  This list though is populated by a Javascript array and the variable is called availableTags.

What I want to do is query a MySQL database for tags and have this happen every time a key is pressed.

I need some help determining how to do this with the jQuery code...

[Here is the source code for Tagit](https://github.com/hailwood/jQuery-Tagit)

I have a function that uses JSONP but I would rather use JSON and modify the hidden select element's id and value so I could easily post this to my php script.

For some reason my function won't work and the script won't return any values.

This is what I have so far: ([you can see the whole code here](http://girlzunderground.com/tagit.php))

```
$(function() {
    $('#demo3').tagit({
        tagSource:function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://girlzunderground.com/php/profile-tags.php",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    txt: $("#test1").val(),
                    t: "books"
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( data );
                }
            });
        },
        triggerKeys:['enter', 'comma', 'tab'],
        allowNewTags: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it figured out.  One main problem I was having was I wasn't sending the header for JSON data.  I needed to specify this header before the JSON would actually work.  Also had to use request.term to populate the txt data varialbe.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $('#demo3').tagit({
        tagSource:function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "php/profile-tags.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    txt: request.term,
                    t: "books"
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( data );
                }
            });
        },
        triggerKeys:['enter', 'comma', 'tab'],
        allowNewTags: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What your trying to do is going to have a lot overhead involved and is not really going to scalable at all.

Regardless, you can bind an event to the input with jquery

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Then have that do an ajax query [ http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ ] which will be a seperate server side script that gets the keywords from your database. Once you have your ajax response you are going to have to import it into tagit.  Looks like the documentation in your link shows you how to do this...I haven't used this script before....looks like calling the add action is what you are looking for.  You need to make sure you don't have duplicates of course.